# How to fix 'gitmodulesPath: disallowed submodule path' on 'git fsck'

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a very old git project, and i did a `git fsck` on it.
I am receiving the following output:

```
git fsck --full
Prüfe Objekt-Verzeichnisse: 100% (256/256), Fertig.
Prüfe Objekte: 100% (35666/35666), Fertig.
error in blob 5ac33d03cc28290156dcd17cf8a4efd95adee7b9: gitmodulesPath: disallowed submodule path: --force
dangling blob dc3821dca2a21a6253c929915011e5b1be932203
```

After some digging in the current state I also checked the history of the `.gitmodules` file because the current version did not have an error.

I found a commit more than a year ago that has the following `.gitmodules` content:

```
[submodule "--force"]
    path = --force
    url = git@gitlab.mygitserver.com:mygroup/myproject.git
```

in the next commit this submodule was deleted again. so somebody clearly was trying something out how submodules work. the problem is now, that it is in the project history.

Is `git fsck` really checking every `.gitmodules` file in history if it had errors at any time?
And how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and was able to remove the error message.

```sh
$ git fsck           
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (686/686), done.
error in blob 6d244aeea44652df31a9a243a339608c7ba0ee5d: gitmodulesPath: disallowed submodule path: --force
```

Someone added a submodule named "--force" and removed it afterwards, but of course it's still in the history.

**Solution (you might want to backup your repo before trying this...)**:

1. Find the commit that introduced your broken "--force" submodule (`git log --all --full-history -- "--force"` helped me)
2. Drop it with interactive rebase (`git rebase -i <commit-hash-1-before>`)

(make sure you drop the commit in all branches)

Now, you should have a "dangling blob" which doesn't belong to any commit. At this point `git fsck` still reports the error.

In order to get rid of the blob:

3. `git reflog expire --expire=now --all` (not 100% sure this is requried)
4. `git gc --prune=now`

Et voila:

```sh
$ git fsck  
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (545/545), done.
```